# Why DBDATE has a signed integer type for year in OLE DB?

Tags: c++, database, oledb

`DBDATE` is defined as below in `oledb.h`

```
typedef struct tagDBDATE
    {
    SHORT year;
    USHORT month;
    USHORT day;
    }   DBDATE;
```

While both `month` and `day` are unsigned, `year` is signed somehow. What is the rationale? Could `year` be a negative value in practice?

Answer (score 0):

The Roman Empire was founded in 27 BC, which is the year -27 (negative).